# VBA Pasting from excel into Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

```
    Sub jede_Grafik_nach_PowerPoint()
'Extras - Verweise: Microsoft PowerPoint x.x Object Library
Dim Grafik As Shape

Dim PP As Object
Set PP = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")


Dim PP_Datei As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PP_Folie As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set PP_Datei = PP.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\akaygun\Desktop\test.pptm")

PP.Visible = msoTrue

'Set PP_Datei = PP.ActivePresentation wenn akt. Präsi sein soll
For Each ws In wb.Sheets

If Left(ws.Name, 3) = "MLK" Then
 'neue Folie einfügen
   PP_Datei.Slides(3).Copy
    PP_Datei.Slides.Paste
    Set PP_Folie = PP_Datei.Slides(PP_Datei.Slides.Count)
 'copypaste
 ws.Shapes("Stunden").Copy

PP_Folie.Shapes.Paste
    PP_Folie.Shapes("Stunden").Top = 315.1991
    PP_Folie.Shapes("Stunden").Left = 22.17449

 ws.Shapes("Tage").Copy

    PP_Folie.Shapes.Paste
    PP_Folie.Shapes("Tage").Top = 10.16945
    PP_Folie.Shapes("Tage").Left = -2.806772


End If

Next ws



End Sub
```

Dear Community,
I am trying to paste diagramms from excel to Powerpoint via VBA automatically.
When running this Sub it always says : "Remote server Computer doesnt exist" 
'462'
I already tried to set a New Presentation instead of an Object but it did not help.

Comment: Which specific line gives this error ?

Comment: there are no specific lines when starting the macro again the error sometimes is at a different line as it was before.

Comment: I found a bad Solution which uses Wait and DoEvents. is there an alternativ? since that slows down the macro

Comment: Your code works on my machine , stick with this and try to close all the open instances of power point and in your code also include closing power point application at the end with PP.Quit , Set PP = Nothing.

Comment: Which excelverison do you use?

Comment: I'm using 2013.

Comment: I have another version that should be the reason . The newer excel versions are way more sensitive for errors